# Typegoose binding referernce to polymorphic model

Tags: mongodb, typescript, mongoose

I have a situation with polymorphic models

```
interface IEvent {
    title: string;
}
class SubscribeEvent implements IEvent {
    @prop()
    title: string;
    @prop({ref: User})
    user: IUser;
}
class NewsEvent implements IEvent {
    @prop()
    title: string;
    @prop({ref: Post})
    post: IPost;
    @prop({ref: User})
    user: IUser;
}
class OrderEvent implements IEvent {
    @prop()
    title: string;
    @prop({ref: Order})
    order: IOrder;
}
```

Now I created a typegoose model:

```
class Card extends Typegoose {
    @prop()
    name: string;
    @prop()
    events: IEvent[];
}
```

How do I correctly map and extract the `Card` instance with populated references?

Comment: For modern typegoose this is done with nested discriminiators https://typegoose.github.io/typegoose/docs/guides/advanced/nested-discriminators